# Couldn't return output with SRC Key in an INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I want the OUTPUT clause to return both the source key and the target key like below :

```
INSERT INTO sales.stores(store_id,store_name) 
    OUTPUT deleted.store_id,deleted.store_name, inserted.store_id,inserted.store_name
    VALUES (4,'Adidas'),(5,'Nike')
```

I am having this following error :

> ```
> The multi-part identifier "deleted.store_id" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "deleted.store_name" could not be bound.
> ```

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. DDL for the table would help, i.e. is `store_id` an `identity` column?

Answer (score 1):

This is [a documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> `DELETED` cannot be used with the `OUTPUT` clause in the `INSERT` statement.

If you think about it, this limitation makes sense, since an `INSERT` statement does not *delete* anything.

So you should just do:

```
INSERT INTO sales.stores (store_id, store_name) 
    OUTPUT inserted.store_id,inserted.store_name
    VALUES (4, 'Adidas'), (5, 'Nike')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cf9d9ce2c28fc388730b21eaeaaac98)**:

```
store_id | store_name
-------: | :---------
       4 | Adidas    
       5 | Nike
```

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, in `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` statements, you can only refer to columns from the target table in the `OUTPUT` clause. In a `MERGE` statement you can refer to columns from both the target and the source.

This cannot be done directly in the INSERT statement because
you don’t have access to the source table.
So you need to use a MERGE statement here :

```
MERGE INTO sales.stores AS TGT
USING ( 

VALUES(4,'Adidas'),(5,'Nike')

) AS SRC (store_id,store_name)
ON 1 = 2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(store_id, store_name) VALUES(store_id,store_name)
OUTPUT
SRC.*, inserted.*;
```

The `INSERT` is only allowed when the MERGE condition is false.